# withCount with other attributes

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function `allArticlesCount` that counts all articles that have `draft 1`.

```
$allArticlesCount = Article::where('draft', 1)->count();
```

I also have a function that counts the number of articles in a specific category, I use `withCount` , but she counts absolutely all the articles, and I only need with `draft 1`

```
$categories = BlogCategory::withCount('articles')->get();
```

The question is, how can I make it so that all articles that have `draft 1` are counted in the `$categories` function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `withCount()` function, like the `with()` function, can use an array as its argument to allow modification of the relationship being counted. In your instance, you'd do the following:

```php
$categories = BlogCategory::withCount(['articles' => function($query){
  $query->where('draft', 1);
}])->get();
```

This will return your `BlogCategory` instances, each with a `articles_count` property indicative of the number of `draft` articles related to each instance.

Alertnatively, you can define a `draftArticles` relationship:

```php
public function draftArticles() {
  return $this->hasMany(Article::class)->where('draft', 1);
  // Note: May need to adjust `hasMany()` to reference proper FK column, etc.
}
```

And perform `withCount()` on that instead:

```php
$categories = BlogCategory::withCount('draftArticles')->get();
```

Each `BlogCategory` instance would have a `draft_articles_count` property reflecting that.

Comment: thanks it worked :)